# Problem in Destroying Firefox Process after some wait of 10 Seconds

Tags: java, process

proc.wait(10,TimesUnit.Seconds) is not working and its not destroying firefox.exe. here's my code. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? When I execute the code, Firefox just opens and the program finishes. It should destroy the process Firefox after 10 seconds. Is the code correct as it should be?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.*; 
import java.lang.management.*; 
public class JavaFirefox 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Creating Process");; 
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
            Process proc = rt.exec("C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox");  
            proc.waitFor(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            proc.destroy(); 
        }   
        catch (Exception t)
        { 
            t.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am expecting that when firefox opens it will wait for 10 seconds and then it will destroy the process.

Comment: You've said what you expect.  What actually happens?  (Please explain clearly.  "is not working" is not a sufficient explanation.)

Comment: [Whether the subprocess represented by this Process object is forcibly terminated or not is implementation dependent.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--)

Comment: Firefox just opens up and the program finishes. It should open up wait for 10 seconds and destroy the process.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. Strangely the code was correct. I just changed my default browser from Firefox and to Google Chrome and the code started working.